# Convert end anchor point to a two beizer handle point

Tags: adobe-illustrator, anchor-point, bezier-curve

In Illustrator it's easy to convert a 2 bezier handle anchor point into a end point (containing no handles) with the anchor point tool - as I did in my attached image:

[image]

**Is it possible to convert that end point (containing no beizer handles) back to a 2 beizer handle point (like it was to start with)?**

Answer (score 2):

A better option than using the 'Convert Anchor Point Tool' is to use the 'Direct Select Tool'. After selecting the tool then HOLD 'option' or 'alt' (You will get a '+' mark on the side of tool).

This will allow you to select individual anchor point handle's, instead of the pair.

More information on [editing objects](http://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/editing-paths.html)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the answer so I might just as well post it here :)

Select the convert anchor point tool and option drag the point. It was hard to find since no visual clue is given that this will happen until you start to drag.